# SQL UPDATE SET one Column to another value and change value in same step

Tags: t-sql

Take the following update statement.

```
UPDATE  TABLE_1
SET     Units2 = ABS(Units1)
        ,Dollars2=ABS(Dallars1)
        ,Units1 =0
        ,Dollars1 =0
WHERE Units1 < 0
AND   Dollars2 = 0
```

Here are my questions,

1) Is this legal?  It parses and it "seems" to work (on the test table), but will it always work or am I just picking the right records to review.

2) is there a better way to do this.

Thanks,

Comment: There could be a better way to do this, but I'm not sure by your example what your ultimate goal is? Are you trying to process invalid data by storing them in Units2/Dollars2?

Comment: Actually, it's a temporary bug fix.  We are receiving data from a legacy db scheduled for decommissioning shortly.  It's a long and arduous task to change the inputs (AS400) so this is the next easiest temporary solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is legal, and as long as you are wanting to essentially keep the old values of `Units1` and `Dollars1` in `Units2` and `Dollars2` that should work

Here's a test:

```
CREATE TABLE #Table_1
(
    Units1 INT,
    Dollars1 MONEY,
    Units2 INT,
    Dollars2 MONEY
)
GO

INSERT INTO #Table_1 (Units1, Dollars1, Units2, Dollars2)
VALUES (-1,12.00,3,0.00)
GO

UPDATE  #TABLE_1
SET     Units2 = ABS(Units1)
        ,Dollars2=ABS(Dollars1)
        ,Units1 =0
        ,Dollars1 =0
WHERE Units1 < 0
AND   Dollars2 = 0
GO

SELECT * 
FROM  #Table_1
```

Outputs:

```
Units1 | Dollars1 | Units2| Dollars2
0      | 0.00     | 1     | 12.00
```

Comment: Thanks.  I ran that test as well.  I was trying to make sure it would always happen that way.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming that you're talking about the Dollars1 column, I think it should be fine. Reads should use the current value, writes are committed after the calculations are done.

If you're questioning it now, though I would suggest breaking it into two statements. You're the author and it's not clear to you. Take a little pity on the guy that has to maintain it, and make it clear now.

Comment: Unfortunately when you follow the logic, you can't do it in 2 updates.  The first update depends on the old value being 0.  Once you run the update, it's not longer 0.  Trust me, I love multiple steps for making something readable.

Comment: @Dayton, can't really tell from his example. Mine was a general statement. But... if you assume that Units2 and Dollars2 are NULL unless processed, it's doable.

Comment: @Dayton -- oops. you're the "he".  :)

Answer (score 1):

Your query is correct and is pretty much the way to do it.