# Re-Assign SIP extension to other user

Tags: sql, t-sql

Good Morning Community..

I am yet again faced with a problem,
I would like to reassign a sip extension from 1 user to another using an update command,
I've found this example [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7433699/sql-update-set-one-column-to-another-value-and-change-value-in-same-step) but I don't know if I can use it or make it do what I want it to do..

```
1   Angie   Angie   Romero      NULL
2   Nina    Nina    Molina      1094
9   Vanessa Vanessa Valdviezo   1091
10  Marcelo Marcelo Limo        NULL
```

1, 2, 9 and 10 are user ID codes.
Field names from left to right as per Jason's request,
`UsuCodigo, usuUsuario, usuNombre, usuApa and Ext`
table name is `lvUser`

Terrible names, I know, I wasn't the original designer of the table.

I want to be able to assign the extension `1091` to user ID `10` and set the extension field for user ID `9` to `NULL`

Above is an example of how it's saved in the DB

If you need more information I will provide it if possible.

Thanks in advance,
Robert.

Comment: what is your desired result? what is sip?

Comment: I want to set the Extension for UsuCodigo 10 to 1094 and the Extension for UsuCodigo 2 to NULL..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you haven't given us the table name or column names, but you could do something like this to move Extension 1094 from User 2 to User 1

```
Update User set SPI = null where UserID = 2
Update User set SPI = 1094 where UserID = 1
```

Comment: I ended up using 2 queries setting sip = NULL where sip = .... and resetting the sip where the UserID = xx